# Refresh ClaimsPrincipal with OpenIDConnect Middleware, MVC Client, Cookies

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a standard way to ask an MVC client using ID4 OIDC middleware to refresh the ClaimsPrincipal when using cookies? It would be nice to just ask the middleware to refresh the ClaimsPrincipal but I don't think that functionality exists.

The code below does work, however, there is no nonce used in the example below - so I'm not sure if that's secure. I'm not sure how the middleware creates the nonce.

Does anyone have an example of properly refreshing the ClaimsPrincipal in an MVC client application using cookies with ID4 OIDC middleware?

### Validate ID token and Return ClaimsPrincipal from ID Token

```
private ClaimsPrincipal ValidateIdentityToken(string idToken, DiscoveryResponse disco  )
    {


        var keys = new List<SecurityKey>();
        foreach (var webKey in disco.KeySet.Keys)
        {
            var e = Base64Url.Decode(webKey.E);
            var n = Base64Url.Decode(webKey.N);

            var key = new RsaSecurityKey(new RSAParameters { Exponent = e, Modulus = n });
            key.KeyId = webKey.Kid;

            keys.Add(key);
        }

        var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = disco.TryGetString(OidcConstants.Discovery.Issuer),
            ValidAudience = "mvc.hybrid",
            IssuerSigningKeys = keys,

            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
        };

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        handler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        SecurityToken token;
        var user = handler.ValidateToken(idToken, parameters, out token);

        //var nonce = user.FindFirst("nonce")?.Value ?? "";
        //if (!string.Equals(nonce, "random_nonce")) throw new Exception("invalid nonce");
       //nonce is always ""
        return user;
    }
```

### Check cookie expiration. Use the refresh token to refresh ID and Access token. Use the above validation to return ClaimsPrincipal

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),

            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = async cookiecontext =>
                {
                    if (cookiecontext.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(".Token.expires_at"))
                    {
                        var expire = DateTime.Parse(cookiecontext.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"]);
                        if (expire <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5) || DateTime.Now > expire)
                        {
                            var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
                            if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);


                            var refreshToken = cookiecontext.Properties.Items[".Token.refresh_token"];
                            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint,
                                "mvc.hybrid",
                                "secret");
                            var response = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);
                            if (!response.IsError)
                            {
                                cookiecontext.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"] = response.AccessToken;
                                cookiecontext.Properties.Items[".Token.refresh_token"] = response.RefreshToken;
                                cookiecontext.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((int)response.ExpiresIn).ToString();
                                cookiecontext.Properties.Items["NextAccessTokenRefresh"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToString();

                                var _Princ = ValidateIdentityToken(response.IdentityToken, disco);

                                cookiecontext.ReplacePrincipal(_Princ);                                    

                                cookiecontext.ShouldRenew = true;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cookiecontext.RejectPrincipal();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

### Wireup ID4 middleware

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000", 
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ClientId = "mvc.hybrid",
            ClientSecret = "secret",


            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api1", "offline_access", "role" },
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnTicketReceived = notification =>
                {
                    notification.Response.Cookies.Append("NextAccessTokenRefresh", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToString());
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },

            SaveTokens = true,

            TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: What is a nonce?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why are you using the id_token for you're claims principle?  You're access token is the one who is suppose to grant you access, which contains you're subjectId,  on your first login create a an empty user record so you can map you're db to subjectId,  then you can store your user profile information in the DB, and next time you need to request it you get it from you're db instead of parsing the token each time

Comment: @Johnny The issue is caching with ID4 middleware. It would be nice to have a single method call that requests that the middleware update the claims principle by going back to the ID4 authority end point and re-process / refetch tokens and transform the ID token into a claims principle. We are not on the same page. The ValidateIdentityToken() was taken from ID4 QuickStarts. it is used to manually validate and transform ID token into claims principle.

Comment: why would need to validate the Identity Token?

Comment: See their client samples for id4. I assume it's part of the security procedure and I assume that their middleware does that check for you.

Comment: If claims are changing frequently, a token is not a good way to transport that data. Use a good old API call to get updated data.

Comment: @leastprivilege To clarify, are you suggesting to create an API method on the ID4 host that simply returns the claims based on the user ID? Like GetClaims(string UserID)? I find that identity is probably not going to change that often, but when it does change I want to test the application can update it's behavior within a certain time frame. I'm currently demoing behavior. So for instance maybe we want long lived cookies for an mvc client but twice a day it refreshes itself against ID4. So if the identity does change, at most the behavior will act on stale data for 12 hours.